# color changing of <p:commandButton> within <h:form> tag when onclick everytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

below is my jsf code, it's working when i write without h:form tag. but if i write within h:form tag its not working.i want it work with form tag. please tell what to do.

```
<script>
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.background='red';
        }
</script>
<script>
function changeColor1(){
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.background='green';   
    }
</script>  
  <p:commandButton value="SYS01" id="btn1" style="background-color:green"/>
  <p:commandButton value="login" id="btn2"  onclick="changeColor()" />
  <p:commandButton id="btn3" value="logout" onclick="changeColor1()" />
```

above code is working. if i write like below its not working.

```
 <head>
  <script>
    function changeColor(){
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.background='red';
            }
    </script>
    <script>
    function changeColor1(){
        document.getElementById('btn1').style.background='green';   
        }
    </script>
</head>
<h:form>  
      <p:commandButton value="SYS01" id="btn1" style="background-color:green"/>
      <p:commandButton value="login" id="btn2"  onclick="changeColor()" />
      <p:commandButton id="btn3" value="logout" onclick="changeColor1()" />
<h:form>
```

Comment: i referred that link. it really helped me.

Comment: now  problem is: when i click on button color is blinking and goes off. but that color to be there until click on button for second time.